# Creating a curve envelope (non-signal appliaction)

Tags: algorithm, math, 2d, curve

I'm working on developing a transportating engineering tool called a swept path analyzer.  Briefly, as a vehicle turns at a roadway intersection, it may steer in a simple arc, but the body moves in a more complex fashion, as described in  Ackermann Steering theory.

The tool I'm using implements Ackermann Steering and generates the 'tracks' a given vehicle creates as it moves through a curve.  These tracks correlate to specific points on the vehicle: the path the center of the vehicle follows, the paths the wheels themselves follow, and the paths the outermost points on the vehicle follow (usually the outside corners).

As I work on my own implementation, I'm faced with the issue of generating a total vehicle 'envelope' which describes the path taken by the outermost point of the vehicle as it makes it's turn at every point along it's turning path.  This generates a complex shape comprised of several arcs and lines.

I'm familiar with signal envelope theory and the mathematical approach.  However, I feel that would be unnecessarily complex and a better approach would be generating the envelope from the points of the vehicle sampled as the vehicle is driven along it's turning path.

This seems like a boundary problem that I've seen solutions for in game development, and I could pursue that avenue, but as I look at this, it makes me think there has to be a simpler approach - perhaps I'm not looking at the problem correctly.

The images below provide a little visual context:

[image: https://www.cotswoldtransportplanning.co.uk/app/uploads/2017/06/swept-path-analysis-01-1331x650.jpg]

[image: https://www.transoftsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ATO_featureimages_clearance_0217.jpg]

Comment: So you always want the outermost of a set of paths? Then find their intersection points and combine the paths accordingly.

Comment: Right.  I could save each point sampled on the vehicle body, compute vectors between, and choose the set of points whose vector diverges away from the vehicle when vectors intersect.

That seemed like the only good way to solve the problem.  But when I resort to a brute-force, near-sighted solution like that, I feel as though I'm missing something important that would make it more robust, simpler / less computationally expensive (though vector calcs generally aren't that bad).

Comment: If you have a more compact curve representation (as set of lines, arcs, curves, whatever) instead of sampled points, this will probably be much faster.

Comment: It could be reduced to that level, but some paths may be splines or complex curves.  In that case, I end up with a big list of simple, very short arcs which all vary slightly from one to the next to model the more complex path...